# Variable Not Working Inside is_author() Array

Tags: custom-taxonomy, author, conditional-tags, variables, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm using a plugin (User Groups) to separate out users into, well, groups, and I need to figure out a way to create a conditional to check if an author is in a certain group. So, using get_term_by and get_objects_in_term, I was able to build a string of author IDs. See below:

```
$taxonomy = 'user-group';
$taxonomy_group_name = 'author-group';
$taxonomy_group_id = get_term_by('slug' , $taxonomy_group_name, $taxonomy, 'OBJECT');
$taxonomy_group_ids = get_objects_in_term($taxonomy_group_id->term_id, $taxonomy);
$taxonomy_id_list = implode(',', $taxonomy_group_ids);
```

So, I can take the list stored in $taxonomy_id_list and echo it out and get a string that looks like the below:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

For the conditional, I should then be able to say:

```
if(is_author(array($taxonomy_id_list))) { }
```

But that doesn't work. If I paste the raw list into the array, it works as it should, but if I try to use the variable inside the array, the conditional does not work.

What am I missing? Why wouldn't that variable work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've converted `$taxonomy_id_list` to a comma separated string then shoved that string into an array. Your array now looks like

```
array(
  "1,2,3,4"
);
```

That is not going to match any author ID.

You are misunderstanding what `implode` does. This--`1,2,3,4,5,6,7`-- is a set of integers. If place in the array like this-- `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`-- you get an array with 7 arguments. If you `implode` the IDs and put that into the array you have this-- `array("1,2,3,4,5,6,7")`-- an array with one argument.

Just skip this step: `$taxonomy_id_list = implode(',', $taxonomy_group_ids);` `$taxonomy_group_ids`, if it `implode`s the way you say, is already the array you need. There is no need to implode it only to try to reconvert it to an array.

Comment: I get what you're saying about the implode, and that makes sense. What I'm not sure about is how I can skip that step. `$taxonomy_id_list` doesn't exist until I define it with the implode function, and if I use the variable a step before, `$taxonomy_group_ids`, I get an error.

Comment: But you have `$taxonomy_group_ids`. Sorry. Didn't notice the variable change.

Comment: Brilliant, got it. 100% makes sense now. `is_author($taxonomy_group_ids)` works for the array with one less step. Thanks so much.